# psql: Keep only one record for each couple of values in two fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two fields of origin and destination locations, and one field with number of travellers in that direction.

[image]

As the table contains data for both directions, I have two records for each couple of locations, for example Record 1 and 3 in the table, are way out and back from A to B.

How do I keep only one record for each couple (Record 1 of the example above) and remove the other one (Record 3)?
In other words: I want to split this data in two table, one for ways out, one for ways back.

Result table 1 of ways out:

[image]

Result table 2 of ways back:

[image]

Alternatively: assuming it's a request that makes sense for some specific reason, how do I sum the value of travellers of way out and back (keep one record with some of travellers of Record 1 + Record 3?

[image]

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to query your table, you can try something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID_from + ID_to, ID_from * ID_to) *
  FROM your_table
```

If you want to delete the redundant rows from your table, you can try something like this :

```
DELETE FROM your_table AS a
 USING ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID_from + ID_to, ID_from * ID_to) *
           FROM your_table
       ) AS b
 WHERE a.ID_from = b.ID_from
   AND a.ID_to = b.ID_to
```